# Excel 2016 Select lowest figure from a row if cell above matches condition

Tags: excel-formula

I need to select lowest value from a row if cell depending on cell above/below so for these two rows:

45 65 98 58 10 32 56 78 65 78 35 49 67 12 54 65
Y  N  Y  Y  N  Y  Y  N  Y  Y  N  Y  Y  N  Y  Y

the answer would be:

Y=32
N=10

I can find it for the whole row of numbers but just don't know how to select or deselect based on the criteria in the other row

Comment: Picture is not attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have

[image]

In `B4` you would write

```
=MIN(    IF( $A$2:$P$2=$A4, $A$1:$P$1, "" )    )
```

And then press [Ctrl+Shift+Enter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d).

---

Explaination

> `IF( $A$2:$P$2=$A4, $A$1:$P$1, "" )`

*reads as*: where `$A$2:$P$2` is equal to `$A4`, consider the adjacent value stored in `$A$1:$P$1`, otherwise consider an empty string.

> `min( ... )`

*reads as*: take the minimum of the just-considered array.